# ¿Como aplicar estilo a una tabla HTML generada con PHP?

Tags: php, html

tengo un archivo php que me muestra datos de una tabla (bd mysql), por otro lado, tengo un archivo HTML donde tengo una tabla con estilos CSS y todo funcionando, me gustaría aplicar estos estilos con los datos extraídos de la base de datos mediante PHP, es posible esto?
He tratado de colocar el código php en el html pero no lo lee y viceversa.

Tabla de php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla con estilos(bootstrap):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso Xampp, base da datos mysql(PHPMYADMIN).

**Aquí el código PHP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ES">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Matxus - información de productos</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php  
  $server ="localhost"; 
  $usuario = "test";
  $password = "1234";
  $bd = "matxus";
  $conexion = mysqli_connect($server,$usuario,$password,$bd) or die("error en la conexion");
// TABLA PROVEEDORES
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM proveedores") or die("error al extraer los datos");
echo '<table border="1">';
  echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th id="idproveedor">Identificador</th>';
    echo '<th id="empresa">Nombre Empresa</th>';
    echo '<th id="comercial">Comercial</th>';
    echo '<th id="telefono">Teléfono</th>';
  echo '</tr>';
  while($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
  echo '<tr>';
    echo  '<td>'.$extraido['idproveedor'].'</td>';
    echo  '<td>'.$extraido['empresa'].'</td>';
    echo  '<td>'.$extraido['comercial'].'</td>';
    echo  '<td>'.$extraido['telefono'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  }
mysqli_close($conexion);
echo '</table>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Código de mi tabla en HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre de Empresa</th>
                <th>Comercial</th>
                <th>Teléfono</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- DATOS A EXTRAER DE BD.PROVEEDORES -->
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Como les había comentado el en archivo HTML, se aplican los estilos. gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No lo lee porque el código php no se puede leer en un archivo con extensión  `.html` por lo tanto , yo recomiendo que dejes todas tus paginas en php para formar después la tabla con todo, porque estas corriendo en un servidor local apache o algo, xampp?.Muestra codigo que llevas para formar esa tabla en php.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Hola muchachos, gracias por vuestro apoyo, he editado la pregunta, agregando el código. gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el HTML completo del HTML de la tabla que te funciona correctamente? Usas clases como `table-responsive` que necesitan ser cargadas y para una respuesta bien formada se necesita el código completo en el que se cargan las hojas de estilos.

Comment: Hace mas de un año desarrolle un mini-framework con PHP nativo, esta en MVC y esta inspiradoen otros framework, aqui realizo peticiones ajax para el uso de la librería DataTable y otras peticiones, puede apoyarte e interesarte. saludos. https://github.com/Oscabrera/Framework-MVC-PHP-puro.git

Answer (score 2):

Primero que todo me uno a la recomendación de la respuesta anterior. y lo que te falta es incluir los estilos pertinentes de bootsrap para que las clases css hagan su trabajo.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Pon esta linea debajo de

```
<title>Matxus - información de productos</title>
```

y se cargaran los estilos, ten en cuenta que se están cargando de internet

Answer (score 1):

primero, baso cualquier punto de vista es una muy mala praxis poner una consulta en un archivo HTML, la principal razón es que el código se hace enredado y difícil de mantener, yo te propongo lo siguiente como primer paso.

Divide el HTML y el PHP en dos archivos, por ejemplo:

index.php y utils.php (es importante que los dos tengan la extensión php ya que la plantilla (tu tabla) tendrá que tener algo de php para generar el resultado.

Ahora vas a incluir el utils.php en tu archivo index.php y vas a llamar a una función que crearemos luego, puede llamarse getTableFromDatabase():

```
 <?php 
 require('utils.php'); 
 $tabla = getTableFromDatabase();
 ?>
```

Dentro de $tabla estará el html de la tabla que quieres pintar.

En el archivo utils.php lo que vas a hacer es crear la función antes nombrada así:

```
<?php  

function getTableFromDatabase()
{
  $server ="localhost"; 
  $usuario = "test";
  $password = "1234";
  $bd = "matxus";
  $conexion = mysqli_connect($server,$usuario,$password,$bd) or die("error en la conexion");

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM proveedores") or die("error al extraer los datos");

$htmlTabla = ""; 

$htmlTabla.= '<table border="1">';
$htmlTabla.= '<tr>';
$htmlTabla.=  '<th id="idproveedor">Identificador</th>';
$htmlTabla.=  '<th id="empresa">Nombre Empresa</th>';
$htmlTabla.= '<th id="comercial">Comercial</th>';
$htmlTabla.= '<th id="telefono">Teléfono</th>';
$htmlTabla.= '</tr>';

  while($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {

  $htmlTabla.=  '<tr>';
    $htmlTabla.=   '<td>'.$extraido['idproveedor'].'</td>';
    $htmlTabla.=   '<td>'.$extraido['empresa'].'</td>';
    $htmlTabla.=   '<td>'.$extraido['comercial'].'</td>';
    $htmlTabla.=   '<td>'.$extraido['telefono'].'</td>';
  $htmlTabla.=  '</tr>';
  }

$htmlTabla.=  '</table>';

mysqli_close($conexion);

return $htmlTabla;

}
```

Luego en el index.php solo hay que imprimir la variable:

```
  <?php echo $tabla; ?>
```

Antes de terminar quiero comentarte que esta no es ni cerca una buena implementación, la he puesto porque con ella puedes mejorar un poco, pero se hace indispensable si quieres ser un buen desarrollador web empieces a usar algún framework (Symfony, Laravel, hay miles), esta forma de programar ya hace más de 10 años que no se usa a nivel profesional.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ok amigo normalmente cuando genero un php que quiero que tenga estilo solo agrego al head la etiqueta style y escribo mi css no se si sea lo que buscas pero ami me funciona de maravillas algo así:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
//Escribe aqui tus reglas de estilo
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//aquí tu código php
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si te interesa, yo tengo creada una sencilla función qque genera las tablas dinámicamente en base a la SQL que se le pase:

```
function CrearTabla($text) {
mysqli_query("set names 'utf8'");
$result=mysqli_query($text) or die("Error en $result <br>MySQL dice: ".mysqli_error());
if (empty($result)){ die("No hay resultados"); 
} else { 
$numfields = mysqli_num_fields($result) or die("Error en $result <br>MySQL dice: ".mysqli_error());

echo "<div class=\"span12 well\"><table id=\"table\" class=\"table\"><thead><tr>";

for ($i=0; $i < $numfields; $i++) // Generar Cabecera
{ echo '<th>'.mysqli_field_name($result, $i).'</th>'; }

echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) // Generar datos
          { echo '<tr><td>'.implode($row,'</td><td>')."</td></tr>"; }

echo "</tbody></table><div>\n";
        }
}
```

Después basta con llamarla así:

```
$sql="tu sentencia SQL";
CrearTabla($sql);
```

Recuerda que en mysqli no existe la función **mysqli_field_name**; pero podemos implementarla de la siguiente manera y así compatibilizar partes de nuestro código que antes teníamos con mysql.

```
//crear funcion fatante en mysqli ( field_name)
function mysqli_field_name($result, $field_offset)
{
    $properties = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $field_offset);
    return is_object($properties) ? $properties->name : null;
}
```

De todas formas, por lo que veo en la segunda imagen, la tabla con estilos, parece un **DataTables**  Estan enlazadas las Librerías de Datatables?.
La tabla no tiene identificador. Añadele un id

```
<table id="tabla" class="table">
```

Y despues en el javascript de datatables debes llamarla así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla').DataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si he entendido correctamente lo que solicitas, pero si entiendo que en el código php, has de incluir las clases css y ids que afecten a la table, thead, tbody, th, tr y td. Antes de nada incluir en tu header el archivo css que contiene los estilos.

```
echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th id="idproveedor">Identificador</th>';
echo '<th id="empresa">Nombre Empresa</th>';
echo '<th id="comercial">Comercial</th>';
echo '<th id="telefono">Teléfono</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
while($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
echo '<tr>';
echo  '<td>'.$extraido['idproveedor'].'</td>';
echo  '<td>'.$extraido['empresa'].'</td>';
echo  '<td>'.$extraido['comercial'].'</td>';
echo  '<td>'.$extraido['telefono'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
```

Creo que es suficiente para que los estilos se apliquen correctamente a tu tabla generada desde código en php.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que ya resolvió este inconveniente, por lo general para dar estilo a una tabla yo recurro a datatable ya sea con bostrap o sin el.  Por lado cargo las librerías de
los css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/Buttons-1.6.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/FixedHeader-3.1.6/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/DataTables-1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

y los js

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/DataTables-1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/DataTables-1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Pueden ser mas o menos librerias dependiendo de lo que quieras añadir a las tablas...
dataTable es muy funcional y tiene muchas caracteristicas

De esta manera armo la tabla y su contenido:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
            <p class="text-center">LISTADO</p>
            </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table id="nombreTabla"  class="table table-striped table-bordered" class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;"># UNIDAD</th>
                        <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">NOMBRE DE UNIDAD</th>
                        <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">CLAVE</th>
                        <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">CANTIDAD DE BIENES</th>
                        <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">PROYECTO</th>
                        <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">CENTRO GESTOR</th>
                        <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">VALIDACIONES</th>
                        <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">ACCIONES:</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                <?PHP
               for($i=0; $i< $totalResultado; $i++){
                $Unidad=$resultadoUnidad[$i]->getCadenaLoc();
                $Clave=$resultadoUnidad[$i]->getCadenaC();
                $Numeros=$resultadoUnidad[$i]->getEnteroAct();
                $Validacion=$resultadoUnidad[$i]->getEnteroVal();
                $Proyecto=$resultadoUnidad[$i]->getCadenaProy();
                $Centro=$resultadoUnidad[$i]->getCadenaCentro();

                ?>
                <tr>
                <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?= $i+1?></td>
                <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?=$Unidad?></td>
                <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?=$Clave?></td> 
                <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?=$Numero?></td>
                <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?=$Proyecto?></td>
                <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?=$Centro?></td>
                <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?=$Validacion?></td>
                <td label style="font-size:10x;">
                    <a href="../codificacion/algo.php?clave_cct=<?=md5($Clave)?>" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search btn btn-info btn-ms" title="BIENES UNIDAD"></a>  
                    <a href="../codificacion/algo.php?clave_cct=<?=md5($Clave)?>" class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode btn btn-info btn-ms" title="ACTUALIZAC&Oacute;N"></a>   

                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>    

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;"># UNIDAD</th>
                    <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">NOMBRE DE UNIDAD</th>
                    <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">CLAVE</th>
                    <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">CANTIDAD</th>
                    <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">PROYECTO</th>
                    <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">CENTRO</th>
                    <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">VALIDACIONES</th>
                    <th label style="font-size:12px; background-color: #32AA00;">ACCIONES:</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

la carga de los datos entre las etiquetas tbody se puede hacer de diversas formas, esta es la mas sencilla  y funciona sin problemas.   Se me olvidaba la llamada al dataTables que puede ser añadida en la cabecera del hmtl, en el php o en un js por separado, cuando se trabaja con tres capas, modelo Mvc etc...
esta es la carga del datatable para que sea 100% funcional $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nombreTabla').DataTable();
} );